# How to read each cell of a column in csv and take each as input for jq in bash

Tags: bash, csv, jq

I am trying to read each cell of CSV and treat it as an input for the JQ command. Below is my code:

**line.csv**

```
| Line |
|:---- |
| 11   |
| 22   |
| 33   |
```

**Code to read CSV:**

```
while read line

do

   echo "Line is : $line"

done < line.csv
```

Output:

```
Line is 11
Line is 22
```

**jq Command**

```
jq 'select(.scan.line == '"$1"') | .scan.line,"|", .scan.service,"|", .scan.comment_1,"|", .scan.comment_2,"|", .scan.comment_3' linescan.json | xargs
```

I have a linescan.json which have values for line, service, comment_1, comment_2, comment_3

I want to read each value of csv and treat the input in jq query where $1 is mentioned.

Comment: please provide some input lines from the your `csv` file and the respective output.

Comment: Each cell of a column have below value:

101
145
558
339

Comment: a CSV is a text file; copy/paste a few lines of it (including the first line) in your question

Comment: @Fravadona please check in the starting the line.csv is there

Comment: Did you open the CSV with a text editor? what is the output of `head -n 4 file.csv`?

Comment: 11
22
33%

is the output for the command (all in new line) @Fravadona

Comment: while read line

do

   echo "Line is : $line"
testline=$(jq 'select(.scan.line == '"$1"') | .scan.line,"|", .scan.service,"|", .scan.comment_1,"|", .scan.comment_2,"|", .scan.comment_3' linescan.json | xargs)
echo $testline
done < line.csv

Comment: @Fravadona Executing the above is giving out an error:
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting ';' or ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
) | .scan.line,"|", .scan.service,"|", .scan.comment_1,"|", .scan.comment_2,"|", .scan.comment_3                  
jq: 1 compile error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Given the input files and desired output:

- line.csv

```
22,Test1
3389,Test2
10,Test3
```

- linescan.json

```json
{
  "scan": {
    "line": 3389,
    "service": "Linetest",
    "comment_1": "Line is tested1",
    "comment_2": "Line is tested2",
    "comment_3": "Line is tested3"
  }
}
```

- desired output:

```
Test2 | 3389 | Linetest | Line is tested1 | Line is tested2 | Line is tested3
```

---

###### Here's a solution with `jq`:

This is a shot in the dark, as you didn't specify what your output should look like:

```sh
jq -sr --rawfile lineArr line.csv '
    (
        $lineArr | split("\n") | del(.[-1]) | .[] | split(",")
    ) as [$lineNum,$prefix] |
    .[] | select(.scan.line == ($lineNum | tonumber)) |
    [
        $prefix,
        .scan.line,
        .scan.service,
        .scan.comment_1,
        .scan.comment_2,
        .scan.comment_3
    ] |
    join(" | ")
' linescan.json
```

---

###### Update: with jq 1.5:

```
#!/bin/bash

jq -sr --slurpfile lineArr <(jq -R 'split(",")' line.csv) '
    ($lineArr | .[]) as [$lineNum,$prefix] |
    .[] | select(.scan.line == ($lineNum | tonumber)) |
    [
        $prefix,
        (.scan.line | tostring),
        .scan.service,
        .scan.comment_1,
        .scan.comment_2,
        .scan.comment_3
    ] |
    join(" | ")
' linescan.json
```

Comment: Thanks, that's worked
This is printing all results in a new line. Could you please tell me how can I print the result in CSV such that line, service, comment_1, comment_2, and comment_3 comes in a row but different columns?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: if line.csv has a second column with values corresponding to the first column. How can we print the second column values also? For example, B1 has a value that is related to A1. So, when printing .scan.line, .scan.service... it also print B column for that specific A column value

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean; you should ask an other question with a sample of your `line.csv` (for ex the raw output of the command `head -n 3 line.csv`), a sample of your `linescan.json`, and your exact desired output from these two input samples.

Comment: line.csv

22,Test1

3389,Test2

10,Test3

JSON:

{
    "scan":
        {
            "line": 3389,
            "service": "Linetest",
            "comment_1": "Line is tested",
            "comment_2": "Line is tested"
        }
} 

Output:

Test2 | 3389 | Linetest | Line is tested | Line is tested

Comment: see the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244234/discussion-between-pawan-and-fravadona).

Comment: I am trying to add another logical condition inside select but it is giving syntax error everytime:
select((.scan.line == ($pNum | tonumber)) && ((!$reach == "FALSE") || (!$state == "closed")) | ... where reach and state are the columns from line.csv

Comment: nvm thanks, I figured it out

select((.scan.line == ($pNum | tonumber)) and (($reach != "FALSE") or (!$state != "closed")) |

Comment: I am trying running the above code in Linux and it is giving error: jq: Unknown option --rawfile
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq

However when I run this on my local terminal it is working fine

Comment: It seems like you have an old version of `jq` installed. What's the output of `jq --version` ?

Comment: it is jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe

Comment: See update for jq 1.5